# How is +id valid inside a RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

In a relative layout I see a pattern as:

```
<TextView 
    android:id=“@+id/txt_id”
    etc
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/some_other_txt”
    etc
/>

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/some_other_txt"

 etc
/>
```

I thought `+id` is used only when creating an id for a widget. Is this a kind of “trick” to layout a widget relative to another widget declared later in the file?

**UPDATE:**
This question is specifically about the RelativeLayout possitioning. Not about the difference in syntax in general as the linked question

Comment: You reference a View **anticipately** (a View which hasn't yet been created in the xml) by using `@+id`. But I prefer creating the View **before** and then refer it  by using `@id`.

Comment: @DiegoFreniche:I think there is no duplicate. My question is about RelativeLayout and not in general the difference between the syntax

Comment: @DerGolem:Is this somewhere documented? I could not find it somewhere

Comment: Oh, now you are asking too much... I can't remember where did I get this bit of info. Maybe, from a book.

Comment: In RelativeLayout the order in which you write your widgets it's not the same as they appear on screen. Android Lint needs to check all relationships too, so maybe this is a way to avoid Lint from giving you warnings

Comment: @DerGolem:I am asking in the sense I could not even google about this trick

Comment: This pdf is in French, but you can always use Google Translate... http://cedric.cnam.fr/~farinone/SETMO/seance2PourSETMO.pdf - Search `@+id > @id`

Answer (score 0):

Its just a reference point for placing the different elements in the layout builder.

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5681389/225503)

> The first time you reference an ID, use the @+ prefix, which tells the resource builder to add the ID,

Here you're making a **forward reference** to a widget & id that's not already defined:

```xml
<TextView 
    android:id=“@+id/txt_id”
    etc
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/some_other_txt”
    etc
/>
```

Here you are **defining** it:

```xml
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/some_other_txt"
```

[More context here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385587/225503)

Comment: But shouldn't be this declared to the widget that has the id assigned?

Comment: And that would be considered the first time you reference it. ;)

Comment: Being an **anticipated reference**, the id is created **before** the Widget has it **explicitly assigned**.